# How to relate webrequest with processid in powershell script

Tags: powershell

Is possible to get the process id of the worker to a specific request in the PowerShell script?

I have some workers in my pool of IIS and I am trying to get the processsid of a worker that has some request working for a long time.
With

```bash
(Get-WebRequest -AppPool "testpool"| where {$_.timeElapsed -gt 100000})
```

We get the request, and we can get the process ids of workers in our Pool but we can't get the relationship between both.

Can you give us some indications to get closer to solving the problem? Thanks.

Regards